# Redirecting in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm relatively new to EmberJS, so any help is appreciated. I'm trying to do something I feel should be theoretically simple - I have a component and on one of the DOM elements, I want to have a click handler which redirects to a route, but I've been unable to figure out how to make that happen.

I have my component:
*//components/sample-card-header.js*

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
export default Component.extend({
  actions: {
    goToSamples() {
      this.transitionTo('samples');
    }
  }
});
```

And my handlebars template:

*//templates/components/sample-card-header.hbs*

`<div class="card_header" {{action "goToSamples" bubble=false}}>Samples</div>`

I know I can just do:
`<div class="card_header" onClick="window.location.href=('/samples')" >` but I'd like to use the router paths.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include the code for that route definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that transitionTo is not available inside of components. You have two options. You could pass the action up to your route by modifying your code to be this.

1.) Create an action in your route to handle the transition and then pass the action up from the component. Follows the actions up, data down mentality of Ember.

component

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
export default Component.extend({
  actions: {
    goToSamples() {
      //this passes the action to the components parent. It could be a route, other component, etc..
      this.sendAction('transition');
    }
  }
});
```

route template.hbs with component

```
{{said-component transition='action-on-route'}}
```

route.js

```
...
actions: {
  action-on-route: function(){
    this.transitionTo('samples')
  }
}
```

2.) You could inject the routing service to the component. This would make transitionTo available to the component through the routing service. I would still suggest option one as it makes the component more extensible.

Your new component code.

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { inject }from '@ember/service';
export default Component.extend({
  router: inject(),
  actions: {
    goToSamples() {
      this.get('router').transitionTo('samples');
    }
  }
});
```

**Another Option**

I just thought of this as I was editing. You could also use the Link-to helper if you simply need to do a transition. The link-to helper provides the ability to change the tagName. So you could render a div with a click event to transition the route using the link-to helper.

Example component.hbs

```
...
{{#link-to 'samples' class='card_header' tagName='div'}}
    Some html
{{/link-to}}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try the first one. I tried injecting the routing service earlier but it didn't work too well.

Comment: Yeah the routing service is private, so it's hard to predict your outcome when using it. I just edited my answer since I injected it wrong lol. But the injection should work, it's just the quick and dirty way and not really recommended.

Comment: Also by using the first one. It makes the component more extensible since you can control the transition from outside of the component. Whereas if the component is controlling the transition, you have no way to change it other than editing the component, and that could not always be the desired result.

Comment: True! Nice, thanks @Joe. I forgot to include the action handler on the nested component template, but once I did that, this works really nicely!

Comment: @JoeHartzell Could you edit your answer to include the public API of the Router service? There is no need to use private API anymore unless someone is working on an old app. It is available since 2.15 https://emberjs.com/api/ember/release/classes/RouterService

Comment: The Router service allows you to use transitionTo from a component using public API

Comment: Yes sorry! I have been working on an app recently that has been on 1.13 until recently, forgot that it was made public. I will change it.

Comment: Thank you :) A lot of people still don’t know about it